# NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I have got a problem with restart httpd service on my server.

When I try `service httpd restart`, it will give me an error:

```
root@server1 [/usr/src]# service httpd restart
AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release /usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf:455
```

I don't really understand what I get an error when i try to restart the httpd service.

Can you please tell me what I have to do to correct the problem?

P.S I need to set the setting correctly in the httpd.conf as I need the rewrite rules to work correctly as it did not work when I try to use `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^google` as it wont do anything to mask the domain name to my domain name.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The error instructs you to look at line 455 in `/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf`. That line likely starts with `NameVirtualHost`, which is no longer necessary. But it is a warning, not an error. Also take a look in the logs (your configuration appears not standard; check in `/var/log` for the httpd logs).

Answer (score 10):

As an elaboration of other answers, do as follow:

1. Open `/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf`
2. Comment bellow lines or similar ones by adding #:

   `NameVirtualHost 188.165.XX.XX:80`

   `<VirtualHost 188.165.XX.XX:80>`
3. Add following line:

   `<VirtualHost *:80>`

(or simply replace 188.165.XX.XX:80 with *:80). Save `httpd.conf` and restart apache, `service httpd restart`.

Comment: I thinking that -1 because only delete with row with NameVirtualHost  is right as is in accepted answer. You can use virtual host with IP and port still in apache 2.4.

Comment: You can, but the important thing to understand is that the name at `VirtualHost` isn't the name of the vhost, it's the name of the interface on which to accept connections. So in most cases `*:80` there is sufficient and less error-prone. The actual name goes into the `ServerName` directive.